# VueJS Transition Group depending on key

Tags: vue.js

So I'm adding numbers to an array.

After a certain timeout, the first item in the array gets spliced and the leave transition applies. However, the transition is being applied to the last item in the array.

I've managed to fix this by simply changing the key to something else:
`:key="item"`. With this change, the leave transition is now correctly applied to the element that was spliced, the first one.

Here is the jsfiddle so you can test it out: https://jsfiddle.net/k375qyfr/2/

What I want to know is, why? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with v-for, by
> default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data
> items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the
> order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure
> it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index. This is
> similar to the behavior of track-by="$index" in Vue 1.x.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

thats why you should have use `:key="item"`